# Multiplayer command-line Chess

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, games, chess

I love a good game of Chess, but what I would love even more is a Chess application that has the following features:

- Has a TUI rather than a GUI and is fully used from the command-line
- Has multiplayer capabilities (something like P2P)
- Is still being maintained (preferable)

So is there something like this that would be compatible with Ubuntu GNOME 15.04? Preferably something from the repositories.

Comment: Interesting: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man6/cutechess-cli.6.html

Answer (score 3):

[Command-line-chess](https://github.com/marcusbuffett/command-line-chess)  does not have multiplayer capacities but can still interest you :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install cl-chess
chess
```

[image]

Comment: Be bold! don't use E4 to begin with :+

Comment: @Rinzwind more like "be safe, protect against the Sicilians!"